# jqGrid setRowData fails

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I cannot update a cell from my grid row select handler.  The cell remains unchanged and the call to setRowData returns false.  What might cause this? I used code from another SO answer and read the online doco for jqGrid.

```
   var _handleRowSelectedInGrid = function( rowId ){
        var rowData = $('#attendantImagesTable').jqGrid( 'getRowData', rowId );
        // rowData looks good here!

        rowData.userLastName = 'HELLO';
        var success = $('#attendantImagesTable').jqGrid( 'setRowData', rowId, rowData );
        // success == false   why?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code snippet, it looks like the call to `setRowData` should have worked. You could try debugging using a non-minified version of jqGrid and step into the call to `setRowData` to see why it is failing.

Alternatively, if you are just setting data in a particular cell, it might be easier to use the [`setCell`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method.

Comment: Thank you - I will try both approaches.  I know this is not an appropriate forum for a question like this, but have you ever tried SlickGrid?

Comment: No, but there are a lot of JavaScript grids these days.